# How can I add a character to the strings of my dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to add an "s" to some of this values for this dictionary (the values are provided by the output of the curl command, here an example:

```
time_connect=0.010868;time_namelookup=0.004235;time_pretransfer=0.043035;time_starttransfer=0.060582;time_total=0.061927
```

I would like to transform that data to something like this:

```
time_connect=0.010868;time_namelookup=0.004235s;time_pretransfer=0.043035s;time_starttransfer=0.060582s;time_total=0.061927s
```

The code below:

```
command = 'curl -s -X POST -w ' + args.param_curl + ' --insecure -vvv ' + args.url
output = check_output(command, shell=True)
dictionary = dict(x.split('=') for x in output.split(';'))
```

I was finding for some information, and I saw that this could be done by using dict.update, but I do not know the way to do that...

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more than one way to do it, but here's a simple way:

```
newDict = {}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    newDict[key] = value + "s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the 's' on all of the times or are you purposely excluding `time_connect`? If you meant to exclude it use this code:

```py
for key, val in dictionary.items():
    if key == "time_connect":
        continue
    dictionary[key] = str(val) + "s"
```

Otherwise just remove the if statement.

Comment: The "time_connect" argument is excluded on purpose, because that value is used by a monitoritation tool.